# отсортировать таблицу по цене

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица

```html
<table class="search_header_tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="r_q" data-targ="q">Объект<i></i></td>
      <td class="r_f" data-targ="f">Этаж<i></i></td>
      <td class="r_rc" data-targ="type_rc">Комнат<i></i></td>
      <td class="r_sq" data-targ="sq">Площадь, м<sup>2</sup><i></i></td>
      <td class="r_tc multi" data-targ="tc"><span>Стоимость, руб</span><i></i></td>
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td" data-targ="renovation"><span>Отделка</span><i></i></td>
      <td class="r_res rotated_td add_td" data-targ="res"><span>Забронировать</span></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!--</table>-->
  <!--<table class="search_result_tab accel" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">-->
  <tbody class="bg-sp">
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n121" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        Самая лучшая новостройка
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">6</td>
      <td class="r_rc">1</td>
      <td class="r_sq">15</td>
      <td class="r_tc">21212</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n119" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        Самая лучшая новостройка
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n118" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        tyr555
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n117" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        vsdvsdv
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n116" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        Самая лучшая новостройка
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n115" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        vsdvsdv
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n114" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        1111111111
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n113" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        vsdvsdv
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n112" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        tyrhge
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">1</td>
      <td class="r_rc">3</td>
      <td class="r_sq">16</td>
      <td class="r_tc">251515</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">0</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n111" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        Самая лучшая новостройка
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">4</td>
      <td class="r_rc">3</td>
      <td class="r_sq">16</td>
      <td class="r_tc">32</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n110" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        Новостройка
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n108" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        Новостройка
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">Эта</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n34" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        tyr555
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">5</td>
      <td class="r_rc">0</td>
      <td class="r_sq">0</td>
      <td class="r_tc">0</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n31" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        1111111111
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">7</td>
      <td class="r_rc">3</td>
      <td class="r_sq">55</td>
      <td class="r_tc">21212</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">1</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n30" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        vsdvsdv
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">5</td>
      <td class="r_rc">4</td>
      <td class="r_sq">6</td>
      <td class="r_tc">3555</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">0</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n29" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
        vsdvsdv
      </td>
      <td class="r_f">5</td>
      <td class="r_rc">5</td>
      <td class="r_sq">16</td>
      <td class="r_tc">32</td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd">0</td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-path="serdtse-stolitsy" id="n" class="tdheight">
      <td class="r_q">
      </td>
      <td class="r_f"></td>
      <td class="r_rc"></td>
      <td class="r_sq"></td>
      <td class="r_tc"></td>
      <!--<td class="r_tcnd"></td>-->
      <td class="r_renovation rotated_td">
        <div class="search_ren_btn search_popup_icon n0"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="r_res">
        <div class="search_reserve_btn search_popup_icon disabled" data-popup="Бронирование" id="orderModal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

как сделать чтобы при клике на класс "r_tc multi" она отсортировалась по ценам от меньшей к большей

Comment: Что здесь цена? Как читать этот лендинг?

Comment: @goodmice видимо td-шки вот с таким классом r_tc

Comment: Почему бы не использовать flex вместо таблицы? Так будет куда проще размещать и сортировать элементы

Comment: @goodmice так сверстали сайт вертска весьма специфичная

Comment: Нужно генерировать таблицу с помощью js, перегенерировать при нажатии на кнопки сортировки. Сортировать при помощи `Array.sort()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобное делают на стороне "логики", если у вас PHP, то на нем. Или же Ajax-ом на тот же PHP. Так как у вас с большей вероятностью будет постраничная навигация, то сортировку делают на стороне логики и уже выводят на view.

Вы должны создать событие на классе `r_tc multi`, который отправляет запрос обработчику, с нужнымы параметрами **`ASD/DESC + price`** => сортирует в нужном порядке => возвращает => показываете.

Если нужно чисто на JS и это единственная таблица (без пагинации), то можете воспользоваться к примеру этим плагином: https://github.com/tristen/tablesort ([DEMO](http://tristen.ca/tablesort/demo/))

Comment: я думал сделать это на php но как я узнаю старый запрос вроде как в куках хранить такие данные не безопасно

Comment: Хранить данные о сартировке в куках вовсе не имеет никакого отношения к безопасности. Это же не пароль в открытом виде, а настройки интерфейса, что как раз таки индивидуальны. Если нужно на долгосрочной основе хранить, можете в cookies, если краткосрочной, то session тоже подойдет.

PS: Ну и даже пароль вы можете спокойно в куках хранить в зашифрованном виде с привязкой по IP, а ключ хранить уже на стороне сервера. Таким образом при хищении кук они будут невалидными, ну а пароль невозможно будет узнать без ключа.

Comment: @Vadim а зачем вообще в куках хранить?

Comment: @PerfectoWeb пароль лучше вообще не хранить в куках, лучше генерировать id и key сессии при каждом входе, удалять старые при неиспользовании.

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин предполагаю, человек хочет, чтобы настройки сортировки не сбились, при переходе на другие страницы. И чтобы в _GET не хранить их. Для этих целей в основном session используют, но и cookie не проблема.

Comment: @PerfectoWeb в таком случае можно какой-нибудь `__settings` в куках выделить и хранить там.все настройки в json base64

Comment: "Подобное делают на стороне "логики"" - подобное можно делать и на стороне клиента, например с помощью AngularJS.

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин разницы вовсе не вижу. Вот предположим вы получили мой защифрованный пароль, он таков SAjv. - каким образом вы дешифруете его у узнаете, что под ним спрятан 16 значный пароль? У меня свой алгоритм и свой ключ шифрования. И вот этот пароль вовсе не дешифровать без кода и базы с ключем.

Comment: @Anamnian если задача небольшая, то тут Angular ни к чему, достаточно старенького JQuery.

Comment: @PerfectoWeb легче проверенным путем, с сессиями и возможностью пользователю самому удалять сессии.

Comment: JS плагин отлично подошёл

Comment: всем огромное спасибо